# Gitlab API. How to get emoji in note?

Tags: gitlab-api

I request for a list of discussions and I want to get emoji from the attached notes.
But I can not find such an api.

Answer (score 0):

The only mention of emojis I see in the api docs is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/award_emoji.html

I’m not quite clear on what you are trying to do — does that help?

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#add-emoji-reactions-on-tasks-objectives-and-key-results) (May 2023) annouces:

> ### Add emoji reactions on tasks, objectives and key results
>
> You can now contribute to tasks, objectives and key results with the addition of emoji reactions for work items.
>
> Before this release, you could only add reactions on issues, merge requests, snippets, and epics.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/award_emojis_for_tasks_objectives_and_key_results.png -- Add emoji reactions on tasks, objectives and key results]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/award_emojis.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9987).

This references the "[Emoji reactions API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/award_emoji.html)", which can:

> ### List an awardable’s emoji reactions
>
> ```
> GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/award_emoji
> GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/award_emoji
> GET /projects/:id/snippets/:snippet_id/award_emoji
> ```